# How to validate object with schema?

Tags: javascript, validation, schema

This is the main file where I have schema and values. I have validation-type which returns true if type is string ect.
Then there is validation file where I should validate values with schema.

```
import * as ValidationTypes from './lib/validation-types'
    import {validate} from "./lib/validation";

const schema = {
  name: ValidationTypes.string,
  age: ValidationTypes.number,
  extra: ValidationTypes.any,
};

const values = {
  name: "John",
  age: "",
  extra: false,
};

let result = validate(schema, values); //return array of invalid keys
console.log(result.length === 0 ? "valid" : "invalid keys: " + result.join(", "));
//invalid keys: age
```

validation-type

```
export function string(param) {
    return typeof param === "string"
  }

  export function number(param) {
    return typeof param === "number"
  }

  export function any(param) {
    return true;
  }
```

and this is validation.js

```
export function validate(schema, values) {
  let invalidValues = []


}
```

And I am stuck, don't know how to continue with validate function.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is somewhat like following code block:

```js
export function validate(schema, values) {
  let invalidValues = [];

  // Make sure schema is an object
  if (typeof schema !== "object") {
    throw new Error("Schema must be an object");
  }

  // Loop over each key of the schema
  Object.keys(schema).forEach((schemaKey) => {
    // Get the validation function associated with
    // the specific key of the validation schema
    const validationFn = schema[schemaKey];

    // Sanity check. Check if the variable associated
    // with the schemaKey is a function or not.
    if (typeof validationFn !== "function") {
      throw new Error("Invalid validation function");
    }

    // Get the validation result of the schemaKey
    // through it's validation function.
    // The schema key is also used in the values passed
    // to this function.
    const validationResult = validationFn(values[schemaKey]);

    // Check if the validation is true
    if (!validationResult) {
      // If the validation is not true
      // Push the error message
      invalidValues.push(
        // `schemaKey` is the name of the variable
        // `validationFn.name` gives the name of the validation function
        // which in this case is associated with variable type
        `[${schemaKey}] must be of type [${validationFn.name}]`
      );
    }
  });

  return invalidValues;
}
```

You can refer this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-brook-8jukz0?file=/lib/validation.js) for better understanding.

Basically, the code is using the name of the validation function to give better validation error results. You can modify the error result pushed to `invalidValues` to get the type of error result you want.